# Grouping Same order Terms of Series: $\sum^{\infty}_{m=0}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{l=0}^{k} \alpha(k,l)x^{2l-k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Im having trouble with manipulating this series such that it can be expressed as a power series.
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{m=0}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{l=0}^{k} \alpha(k,l)x^{2l-k}
$$
The coefficients are left as arbitrary as for my work with the problem they are needless complicated to be stated here. The sum will obviously range over all the integers and will look something like...
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} \beta(n)x^{n}
$$
... as each sum over $l$ ranges from terms of order $-k$ and $k$. However, finding an expression for $\beta(n)$ has proved to be very challenging because of variances between behaviors of negetive orders and positive orders aswell as odd and even. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. If your curious this odd sum came from work Im doing with reciprocals of Bessel Functions.

Edit:
On further inspection of my work $\alpha(k,l)$ does depend on $m$. It was wrapped up in definitions of definitions of various terms and so I missed its dependence. The revised sum looks as such:
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{m=0}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{l=0}^{k} \alpha_{m}(k,l)x^{2l-k}
$$

Comment: @AnnieCarter It only appears as the upper bound of the summation over k. Thus you cant factor out the outer sum over m as you would neglect all the previous terms of the sum over m. Which is to say the last term of the sum over  m is what you put.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: $$\beta(n)=\sum_{0\le l\le k\le m\atop n=2l-k}\alpha(k,l)=\sum_{l\ge\max(n,0)\atop m\ge 2l-n}\alpha(2l-n,l)=\sum_{l\ge\max(n,0)}(\alpha(2l-n,l)\cdot(+\infty))$$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient $\beta(n)$ includes one copy of the summand $\alpha(k, l)$ for each triple $(k, l, m)$ such that $2l - k = n$ and $0 \leq l \leq k \leq m$. I'll try to restate this in terms of triples $(l, m, n)$. We have
$$ 2l - k = n \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad k = 2l - n. $$
We have
$$ l \leq k \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad l \leq 2l - n \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad n \leq l. $$
Since we also need $0 \leq l$, we can conclude that $l \geq \max\{0, n\}$.
Finally, we have
$$ k \leq m \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad 2l - n \leq m. $$
Putting these together,
$$ \beta(n) = \sum_{l=\max\{0, n\}}^\infty \sum_{m=2l - n}^\infty \alpha(k, l). $$

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer after I correct for the fact that I stated the problem wrong for you. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user872633 You may upvote and accept the answer you are satisfied with.

Answer (score 1):

We transform the triple sum until we obtain $\beta(n)$ explicitly.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}&\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{l=0}^k\alpha_m(k,l)x^{2l-k}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq l\leq k\leq m\leq \infty}\alpha_m(k,l)x^{2l-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=l}^{\infty}\sum_{m=k}^{\infty}\alpha_m(k,l)x^{2l-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=k+l}^\infty\alpha_m(k+l,l)x^{l-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{l=\max\{0,n\}}^{\infty}\sum_{m=2l-n}^\infty\alpha_m(2l-n,l)}\right)x^{n}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\color{blue}{\beta(n)}x^n
> \end{align*}
> which explicitly gives $\beta(n)$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) write the index range more conveniently to better see what's going on in the next step.
- In (2) we rearrange the sums starting with the indices in (1) from left to right.
- In (3) we shift the middle sum starting with $k=0$.
- In (4) we set $n:=l-k$ and eliminate $k$ by substituting $k=l-n$. By inspection we see the index $l$ starts with $\max\{0,n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\beta(n)=\sum_{0\le l\le k\le m\atop n=2l-k}\alpha_m(k,l)$$$$=\sum_{l\ge\max(n,0)}\sum_{m\ge2l-n}\alpha_m(2l-n,l).$$